# Unity3D issue with Euler angles/clamp

Tags: unity-game-engine

For a certain wall climbing feature, I have a trigger on a wall object and when I enter it my LimitRotation method is called, but my player camera snaps to the value that my Mathf.Clamp() is set to, as I enter the trigger.

So for example if I enter the trigger whilst I am facing 90 degrees on the y-axis, I will automatically snap to 20 degrees on the y-axis, which is what my clamp is set to below.

```cs
private float minYRot = -20f;
private float maxYRot = 20f;

public void LateUpdate()
    {

        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(xRotation, player.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0f);
        player.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

        if (wallClimb.climbing == true)
        {
            LimitRotation();
        }
    }

public void LimitRotation()
{
     Vector3 playerEulerAngles = player.rotation.eulerAngles;

     playerEulerAngles.y = (playerEulerAngles.y > 180) ? playerEulerAngles.y - 360 : playerEulerAngles.y;
     playerEulerAngles.y = Mathf.Clamp(playerEulerAngles.y, minYRot, maxYRot);

     player.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(playerEulerAngles);
}
```

All I want my clamp to do is restrict my left and right movement when I am climbing a wall, which it does. It is just the initial camera "snap" that I can't seem to fix.

Comment: I think you rather would want to either take a snapshot of the rotation when you start climbing a wall and clamp the rotation against that original rotation ... or alternatively simply clamp the rotation according to the normal of the wall you are climbing on ... both requires more information than just the player's current absolute world space rotation ...

Comment: I added a currentRotation float and used Quaternion rotation & Quaternion AngleAxis to get the currentRotation value as I start climbing, but it makes the problem worse.